# Error while using saved logistic regression model on scoring vector data -The columns of A don't match the number of elements of x. A: 6011, x: 232964

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, one-hot-encoding

0

I'm getting error while using saved logistic regression model on scoring vector data.

SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$Lambda$8457/886152956: (structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>) => structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>).

**Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The columns of A don't match the number of elements of x. A: 6011, x: 232964**

My training vector has length 6011[image]
My scoring / testing vector has length 232964 [image]

I believe this length is sum of the unique values present in the features. I'm performing string indexing and then one hot encoding on categorical features and then combining the categorical vectors and numerical features and then passing it to vector assembler to create the final feature and then scaling it using min max scaler.